# Using the WooCommerce API to get the country/state lists

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I"m using the [WooCommerce API](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Countries.html) to get the country list. I am doing:

```
$woo_countries = new WC_Countries();
$countries = $woo_countries->get_allowed_countries();
```

However, how does one get the state list for the default selected country? Also, when the user changes the country, does Woo have something built in that I can apply to the country field to update the states box or do I have to build that functionality myself?

Also, I know I can get the states for a country via doing:

```
$woo_countries->get_states(country_code);
```

...but I'm not sure how to get the default selected country to pass in to it?

I also know they have a combined country/state list you can load in but that's really messy and far too long for usability.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this , You still need to go for some javascript to make it work.I do not know if there is any way by default to make state drop-down list work as according to country drop-down list.I think it is helpful, give a try and let me know, if it worked.

```
global $woocommerce;
$countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
$countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
$default_country = $countries_obj->get_base_country();
$default_county_states = $countries_obj->get_states( $default_country );
```

so this makes your countries dropdown

```
global $woocommerce;
$countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
$countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
echo '<div id="my_custom_countries_field"><h2>' . __('Countries') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field('my_country_field', array(
'type'       => 'select',
'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
'label'      => __('Select a country'),
'placeholder'    => __('Enter something'),
'options'    => $countries
)
);
echo '</div>';
```

and State dropdown

```
    global $woocommerce;
    $countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
    $countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
    $default_country = $countries_obj->get_base_country();
    $default_county_states = $countries_obj->get_states( $default_country );

    echo '<div id="my_custom_state_field"><h2>' . __('States') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field('my_state_field', array(
    'type'       => 'select',
    'class'      => array( 'chzn-drop' ),
    'label'      => __('Select a state'),
    'placeholder'    => __('Enter something'),
    'options'    => $default_county_states
    )
    );
    echo '</div>';
```

You need some javascript to make it work as you want. You may consider going through  [woocommerce_form_field](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#1644-1865) .

***I have added the below code on my functions.php and the screenshot shows what I am getting .Need to know about your checkout page to make it better.***

*"I believe it is all about creating the same HTML elements as in default checkout page."*

```
//Reordering woocommerce billing form on checkout page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields','reorder_woo_billing_fields' );
function reorder_woo_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    //$fields2['billing']['billing_email'] = $fields['billing']['billing_email'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_first_name'] = $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_last_name'] = $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_company'] = $fields['billing']['billing_company'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_address_1'] = $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_address_2'] = $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_city'] = $fields['billing']['billing_city'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_country'] = $fields['billing']['billing_country'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_state'] = $fields['billing']['billing_state'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_postcode'] = $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'];
    $fields2['billing']['billing_phone'] = $fields['billing']['billing_phone'];

    $fields2['billing']['billing_country']['class'] = array('box', 'form-row form-row-first address-field update_totals_on_change validate-required woocommerce-validated');
    $fields2['billing']['billing_state']['class'] = array('box', 'form-row form-row-last address-field validate-required validate-state woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field');
    $fields2['billing']['billing_postcode']['class'] = array('box', 'form-row form-row-first address-field validate-required validate-postcode');
    $fields2['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('box', 'form-row form-row-last validate-required validate-phone');
    //$fields2['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('box', 'form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-email');
    $fields2['billing']['billing_postcode']['clear'] = '';
    $fields2['shipping'] = $fields['shipping'];
    $fields2['account'] = $fields['account'];
    $fields2['order'] = $fields['order'];

     return $fields2;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'woocommerce_countries_states', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_countries_states( $checkout ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
    $countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
    $default_country = $countries_obj->get_base_country();
    $default_county_states = $countries_obj->get_states( $default_country );


    $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['billing_country'] = array(
        'type'              => 'select',
        'label'             => __( 'Default Contries', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'          => true,
        'options'    => $countries
    );

    $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['billing_country'] = array(
        'type'              => 'select',
        'label'             => __( 'Default Contries', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'          => true,
         'options'    => $default_county_states
    );
}
```

HTML I am getting is somehow like( For country chosen United States(US) ):-

```
<p class="form-row form-row box form-row form-row-first address-field update_totals_on_change validate-required woocommerce-validated validate-required" id="billing_country_field"><label for="billing_country" class="">Country <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><div class="select2-container country_to_state country_select" id="s2id_billing_country" style="width: 100%;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-1">United States (US)</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-offscreen">Country *</label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-1" id="s2id_autogen1"></div><select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select " tabindex="-1" title="Country *" style="display: none;"><option value="">Select a country…</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AL">Albania</option><option value="DZ">Algeria</option><option value="AD">Andorra</option><option value="AO">Angola</option><option value="AI">Anguilla</option><option value="AQ">Antarctica</option><option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option><option value="AR">Argentina</option><option value="AM">Armenia</option><option value="AW">Aruba</option><option value="AU">Australia</option><option value="AT">Austria</option><option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option><option value="BS">Bahamas</option><option value="BH">Bahrain</option><option value="BD">Bangladesh</option><option value="BB">Barbados</option><option value="BY">Belarus</option><option value="PW">Belau</option><option value="BE">Belgium</option><option value="BZ">Belize</option><option value="BJ">Benin</option><option value="BM">Bermuda</option><option value="BT">Bhutan</option><option value="BO">Bolivia</option><option value="BQ">Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba</option><option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option><option value="BW">Botswana</option><option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option><option value="BR">Brazil</option><option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option><option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option><option value="BN">Brunei</option><option value="BG">Bulgaria</option><option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option><option value="BI">Burundi</option><option value="KH">Cambodia</option><option value="CM">Cameroon</option><option value="CA">Canada</option><option value="CV">Cape Verde</option><option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option><option value="CF">Central African Republic</option><option value="TD">Chad</option><option value="CL">Chile</option><option value="CN">China</option><option value="CX">Christmas Island</option><option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option><option value="CO">Colombia</option><option value="KM">Comoros</option><option value="CG">Congo (Brazzaville)</option><option value="CD">Congo (Kinshasa)</option><option value="CK">Cook Islands</option><option value="CR">Costa Rica</option><option value="HR">Croatia</option><option value="CU">Cuba</option><option value="CW">CuraÇao</option><option value="CY">Cyprus</option><option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option><option value="DK">Denmark</option><option value="DJ">Djibouti</option><option value="DM">Dominica</option><option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option><option value="EC">Ecuador</option><option value="EG">Egypt</option><option value="SV">El Salvador</option><option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="ER">Eritrea</option><option value="EE">Estonia</option><option value="ET">Ethiopia</option><option value="FK">Falkland Islands</option><option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option><option value="FJ">Fiji</option><option value="FI">Finland</option><option value="FR">France</option><option value="GF">French Guiana</option><option value="PF">French Polynesia</option><option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option><option value="GA">Gabon</option><option value="GM">Gambia</option><option value="GE">Georgia</option><option value="DE">Germany</option><option value="GH">Ghana</option><option value="GI">Gibraltar</option><option value="GR">Greece</option><option value="GL">Greenland</option><option value="GD">Grenada</option><option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option><option value="GT">Guatemala</option><option value="GG">Guernsey</option><option value="GN">Guinea</option><option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option><option value="GY">Guyana</option><option value="HT">Haiti</option><option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option><option value="HN">Honduras</option><option value="HK">Hong Kong</option><option value="HU">Hungary</option><option value="IS">Iceland</option><option value="IN">India</option><option value="ID">Indonesia</option><option value="IR">Iran</option><option value="IQ">Iraq</option><option value="IM">Isle of Man</option><option value="IL">Israel</option><option value="IT">Italy</option><option value="CI">Ivory Coast</option><option value="JM">Jamaica</option><option value="JP">Japan</option><option value="JE">Jersey</option><option value="JO">Jordan</option><option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option><option value="KE">Kenya</option><option value="KI">Kiribati</option><option value="KW">Kuwait</option><option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option><option value="LA">Laos</option><option value="LV">Latvia</option><option value="LB">Lebanon</option><option value="LS">Lesotho</option><option value="LR">Liberia</option><option value="LY">Libya</option><option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option><option value="LT">Lithuania</option><option value="LU">Luxembourg</option><option value="MO">Macao S.A.R., China</option><option value="MK">Macedonia</option><option value="MG">Madagascar</option><option value="MW">Malawi</option><option value="MY">Malaysia</option><option value="MV">Maldives</option><option value="ML">Mali</option><option value="MT">Malta</option><option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option><option value="MQ">Martinique</option><option value="MR">Mauritania</option><option value="MU">Mauritius</option><option value="YT">Mayotte</option><option value="MX">Mexico</option><option value="FM">Micronesia</option><option value="MD">Moldova</option><option value="MC">Monaco</option><option value="MN">Mongolia</option><option value="ME">Montenegro</option><option value="MS">Montserrat</option><option value="MA">Morocco</option><option value="MZ">Mozambique</option><option value="MM">Myanmar</option><option value="NA">Namibia</option><option value="NR">Nauru</option><option value="NP">Nepal</option><option value="NL">Netherlands</option><option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option><option value="NC">New Caledonia</option><option value="NZ">New Zealand</option><option value="NI">Nicaragua</option><option value="NE">Niger</option><option value="NG">Nigeria</option><option value="NU">Niue</option><option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option><option value="KP">North Korea</option><option value="NO">Norway</option><option value="OM">Oman</option><option value="PK">Pakistan</option><option value="PS">Palestinian Territory</option><option value="PA">Panama</option><option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option><option value="PY">Paraguay</option><option value="PE">Peru</option><option value="PH">Philippines</option><option value="PN">Pitcairn</option><option value="PL">Poland</option><option value="PT">Portugal</option><option value="QA">Qatar</option><option value="IE">Republic of Ireland</option><option value="RE">Reunion</option><option value="RO">Romania</option><option value="RU">Russia</option><option value="RW">Rwanda</option><option value="ST">São Tomé and Príncipe</option><option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option><option value="SH">Saint Helena</option><option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option><option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option><option value="SX">Saint Martin (Dutch part)</option><option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option><option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option><option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option><option value="SM">San Marino</option><option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="SN">Senegal</option><option value="RS">Serbia</option><option value="SC">Seychelles</option><option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option><option value="SG">Singapore</option><option value="SK">Slovakia</option><option value="SI">Slovenia</option><option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option><option value="SO">Somalia</option><option value="ZA" selected="selected">South Africa</option><option value="GS">South Georgia/Sandwich Islands</option><option value="KR">South Korea</option><option value="SS">South Sudan</option><option value="ES">Spain</option><option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option><option value="SD">Sudan</option><option value="SR">Suriname</option><option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option><option value="SZ">Swaziland</option><option value="SE">Sweden</option><option value="CH">Switzerland</option><option value="SY">Syria</option><option value="TW">Taiwan</option><option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option><option value="TZ">Tanzania</option><option value="TH">Thailand</option><option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option><option value="TG">Togo</option><option value="TK">Tokelau</option><option value="TO">Tonga</option><option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option><option value="TN">Tunisia</option><option value="TR">Turkey</option><option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option><option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option><option value="TV">Tuvalu</option><option value="UG">Uganda</option><option value="UA">Ukraine</option><option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option><option value="GB">United Kingdom (UK)</option><option value="US">United States (US)</option><option value="UY">Uruguay</option><option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option><option value="VU">Vanuatu</option><option value="VA">Vatican</option><option value="VE">Venezuela</option><option value="VN">Vietnam</option><option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option><option value="EH">Western Sahara</option><option value="WS">Western Samoa</option><option value="YE">Yemen</option><option value="ZM">Zambia</option><option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option></select><noscript>&lt;input type="submit" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="Update country" /&gt;</noscript></p>
<p class="form-row form-row box form-row form-row-last address-field validate-state woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field validate-state validate-required" id="billing_state_field" data-o_class="form-row form-row box form-row form-row-last address-field validate-required validate-state woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field validate-required validate-state" style="display: block;"><label for="billing_state" class="">State <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><div class="select2-container state_select" id="s2id_billing_state" style="width: 100%;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-491">Select an option…</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen491" class="select2-offscreen">State <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-491" id="s2id_autogen491"></div><select name="billing_state" id="billing_state" class="state_select" placeholder="" tabindex="-1" title="Province " style="display: none;"><option value="">Select an option…</option><option value="AL">Alabama</option><option value="AK">Alaska</option><option value="AZ">Arizona</option><option value="AR">Arkansas</option><option value="CA">California</option><option value="CO">Colorado</option><option value="CT">Connecticut</option><option value="DE">Delaware</option><option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option><option value="FL">Florida</option><option value="GA">Georgia</option><option value="HI">Hawaii</option><option value="ID">Idaho</option><option value="IL">Illinois</option><option value="IN">Indiana</option><option value="IA">Iowa</option><option value="KS">Kansas</option><option value="KY">Kentucky</option><option value="LA">Louisiana</option><option value="ME">Maine</option><option value="MD">Maryland</option><option value="MA">Massachusetts</option><option value="MI">Michigan</option><option value="MN">Minnesota</option><option value="MS">Mississippi</option><option value="MO">Missouri</option><option value="MT">Montana</option><option value="NE">Nebraska</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="NH">New Hampshire</option><option value="NJ">New Jersey</option><option value="NM">New Mexico</option><option value="NY">New York</option><option value="NC">North Carolina</option><option value="ND">North Dakota</option><option value="OH">Ohio</option><option value="OK">Oklahoma</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option><option value="RI">Rhode Island</option><option value="SC">South Carolina</option><option value="SD">South Dakota</option><option value="TN">Tennessee</option><option value="TX">Texas</option><option value="UT">Utah</option><option value="VT">Vermont</option><option value="VA">Virginia</option><option value="WA">Washington</option><option value="WV">West Virginia</option><option value="WI">Wisconsin</option><option value="WY">Wyoming</option><option value="AA">Armed Forces (AA)</option><option value="AE">Armed Forces (AE)</option><option value="AP">Armed Forces (AP)</option><option value="AS">American Samoa</option><option value="GU">Guam</option><option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option><option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option><option value="UM">US Minor Outlying Islands</option><option value="VI">US Virgin Islands</option></select></p>
```

[image]   [image]

***New visitors Please consider going through edits,to know  how this answer has been changed .**

Comment: Why do you need to put them inside a `woocommerce_form_field` call? Does this add some functionality over creating your own form fields with the data?

Comment: @Brett if you have gone through its definition you might have noticed, how it is defined , It has used some functions for sensitization and validation, beside this , We can simple consider following woocommerce coding style to make it look organized , that will be helpful for debugging .

Comment: @Brett may be there are some more benefit, you might have knowledge , if you will edit my answer to make it better, I will be pleased .

Comment: @Brett based on the comments I have given on rnevius answer, I have edited my answer, I hope you will try it and update me with status .

Comment: Thing is we are not using the default checkout; we have our own form outside of Woo that we are trying to hook into Woo so we can use their cart and checkout procedure. The only real issue at the moment is repopulating the state field on country change. I can easily write my own AJAX function, but if there was something within Woo that I could already make use of then that would be good. :)

Comment: @Brett I still think you can use it,as I think the dropdown is working based on css id and class, so use the same for your checkout page, and the required ajax code is present in woocommerce, so It should work.Basically I think you need to generate same HTML selectbox .

Comment: Hmm ok, I will see how I go.

Comment: @Brett ok, please find time to update , I would like to know if it works, It should as I am currently developing a custom google analytics plugin and doing something like that which is working fine .

Comment: I gave this a try but when I changed country it didn't change the state.

Comment: @Brett I will install a woocommerce today and try it and let you know, what I get, just after leaving office.

Comment: @Brett Can you give me better idea about your checkout page ?

Comment: @Brett perhaps, it is somehow different from you need , but I have no idea about your checkout page. so I tried to override my checkout page using hooks and I think it is working, as you can see the place of the fields is also rearranged, you might have noticed it during your try. please match the HTML generated, if it is matching or having some difference ?

Comment: I ended up just doing a state dropdown for our local country and when they changed the country it changed it to a text field so haven't tried what you added above, but it seems like it would work from what you're saying so I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: @Brett thank you , I wish you will get things very correct and your project will be completed in a great way . :) (y)

Comment: If someone would have this code and put it on their registration page:

<?php
 $countries_obj = new WC_Countries();
 $countries  = $countries_obj->get_allowed_countries();
 woocommerce_form_field('billing_country',array(
 'type'  => 'select',
 'class'  => array('chzn-drop'),
 'label'  => __('Country'),
 'placeholder' => __('Choose your country.'),
 'options' => $countries,
 'required' => true,
 'clear'  => true
 ));
?>

How would someone add the JavaScript part to make it look like a real WooCommerce dropdown, as now I only got a simple HTML Dropdown box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh It has been so long, but, the plan was not to write javascript perhaps, the plan was to generate HTML in a way so that the existing woocommerce javascript will work on it. but if you want to write your own javascript, perhaps it will be to change the select box for state, I guess. then just enqueue js and write code for it, but take care of conflict that may arise with woocommerce script, if it is randering in the page you are coding .

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu

Thanks for actually responding to this rather old thread, but it's not that I want to directly write custom JavaScript, but what I'm trying to do is add the country dropdown list to the Registration Page, and I would like to have the original WooCommerce dropdown/select (look and feel) as on the Checkout page. As I understand that the JavaScript for this dropdown isn't actually loaded on the Registration page, I therefore wonder how I would be able to add this and only where needed.

As I currently have this code: https://pastebin.com/ihJH5zwi (line 66)

Comment: I got my own question started which if you would be able to assist me you could reply to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373166/woocommerce-country-selection-on-registration

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh I am quite busy with some work because of deadline, I will look into your question, my good wishes to you.

Answer (score 5):

This is referred to as the "base country" by WooCommerce:

```
$woo_countries = new WC_Countries();

// Get default country
$default_country = $woo_countries->get_base_country();

// Get states in default country
$states = $woo_countries->get_states( $default_country );
```

Read more [in the API docs](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Countries.html#_get_base_country).

It should be noted that the [default WooCommerce billing form template logic](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-billing.php#L38) ensures that the default country and state *are* pre-selected. Here's what it looks like:

```
<?php foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The third argument passed to `woocommerce_form_field()` ensures that the default country and state are pre-populated.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will need to build my own Ajax script to change the state field on country selection?

Comment: @Brett , this behavior is actually already included with WC if you use its form functions. Please see my edit. Note that you *will* need to write your own AJAX function, if you want non-default, selected country changes to also update the State options.

Comment: @rnevius 
 
I think he can consider using  `woocommerce_checkout_fields` hook and clases to make the drop down work with his country and state lists. `$fields2['billing']['billing_country']['class'] = array('box', 'form-row form-row-first address-field update_totals_on_change validate-required woocommerce-validated');
 $fields2['billing']['billing_state']['class'] = array('box', 'form-row form-row-last address-field validate-required validate-state woocommerce-invalid woocommerce-invalid-required-field');` not tried it for this case , but I think it may work .

Comment: @rnevius he can use his custom state list and country list with this hook that may help him to skip coding the javascript , but I have not tested it.This code is from a woocommerce plugin I have developed before some month .